# How to use Angular form validation on other elements like div?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

I am using angular form validation using the below code

```
<form ng-app="" ng-controller="validateCtrl" name="myForm" novalidate>
  <p>Username:<br>
   <input type="text" name="user" ng-model="user" required>
     <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid">
         <span ng-show="myForm.user.$error.required">Username is required.</span>
      </span>
 </p>
</form>
```

But if i want to use like this:

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="validateCtrl" name="myForm" novalidate>
  <p>Username:<br>
   <input type="text" name="user" ng-model="user" required>
     <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid">
         <span ng-show="myForm.user.$error.required">Username is required.</span>
      </span>
 </p>
</div>
```

But this is not working.
Is there is any way to do this work? without using any other libraries.

jsfiddle:[link](http://jsfiddle.net/bpbhat777/jjkj4jjg/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `ngForm` directive ([here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm)) in order to enable the `$pristine`, `$dirty`, `$valid`, `$invalid` services within it:

just define it this way:

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="validateCtrl" name="myForm" novalidate ng-form>
```

Here an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/s5efjzue/

Answer (score -1):

Why not wrap the form in a div? This might achieve what you're looking for.

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="validateCtrl">
  <form name="myForm" novalidate>
    <p>Username:<br>
     <input type="text" name="user" ng-model="user" required>
       <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid">
           <span ng-show="myForm.user.$error.required">Username is required.</span>
        </span>
   </p>
  </form>
</div>
```